# Get stock of combination in a product (PrestaShop)

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.6

I'm using PrestaShop's 1.6.x webservice, and I can't find anywhere in the docs how to get the available stock of a combination of a product (for example, size S, color Blue of T-shirt XYZ).

Is it possible to get that value from the webservice? If "yes", how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.
You can do that by using the

```
../api/stock_availables
```

function. The details of a specific product are hidden in the details of a single `stock_available` record:
(simplified)

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <stock_available>
        <id>
            <![CDATA[ 406 ]]>
        </id>
        <id_product xlink:href="http:...">
           <![CDATA[ 75 ]]>
        </id_product>
           <id_product_attribute xlink:href="http:...">
           <![CDATA[ 325 ]]>
        </id_product_attribute>
        <quantity>
           <![CDATA[ 99 ]]>
        </quantity>
    </stock_available>
</prestashop>
```

`id_product` refers to your product 
`id_product_attribute` is a special one:

- When your product has no combinations (size, color, etc) this id will
  be 0
- When your product does have combinations, this id is the
  combination_id of that specific combination.

Hope this helps